# I can download ftp files from hmi to some system and other system i couldnt . Iam using microsoft internet trasfer control 6.0 in vb6 application

Tags: ftp, vb6

Inet control download working only in few system  and Why its not working to all systems? i have added msinet.ocx file in the system  directory according to their bit version and registered it successfully. I tested in  4 system which has  windows 10 Os .Out of 4, two system run my application and downloaded files and other two system not downloading files but its connected i can see the files too, that is also a windows 10 os . what could i do to solve the issue.

I tried by disabling windows firewall and other anty  virus software . but i couldnt download it.

it was looping in the below code and moving to the next line of code . when i check the local folder its not downloaded.

```
Inet1.Execute , "GET " & FtpFile & " " & LoclFilNm 
Do Until Inet1.StillExecuting = False 
    DoEvents 
Loop
```

please help me i am  a beginner..

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: no i didnt get any error message . it was looping in the below code and moving to the next line of code . when i check the local folder its not downloaded. Inet1.Execute , "GET " & FtpFile & " " & LoclFilNm
Do Until Inet1.StillExecuting = False
DoEvents
Loop

Comment: Are there any other differences between the systems? Do they all have the same local folder?

Comment: I tested in windows 10 and 11 systems which has 64 bit . I wrote code for downloading files in to    LoclFilNm = (App.Path & "\Temp\" & FtpFile)

Comment: The same local path is existing there